# Why grub-probe command fails?

Tags: grub2, encryption

Why does `sudo grub-probe --target=cryptodisk_uuid -d /dev/sdaX` fail?
I have tried /dev/sda. I have tried on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. This command never works.

This does work:

```
sudo grub-probe -v --target=cryptodisk_uuid -d /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt
```

but this seems pretty useless. I mean if I have to specify the drive from /dev/mapper it has already been unlocked, which is only possible if I know which drive is encrypted. Shouldn't Grub be looking for encrypted drives during bootup, before any drives are unlocked?

```
hercules@NB2000:~$ lsblk -pf
NAME                                    FSTYPE      LABEL    UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
/dev/sda                                                                                            
├─/dev/sda1                             ext4                 ab5ce54d-4864-45df-9bf5-9fa6d31f452e   /boot
├─/dev/sda2                                                                                         
└─/dev/sda5                             crypto_LUKS          6a09182f-d71a-48d9-adc0-d1555cda819d   
  └─/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt              LVM2_member          GF6wWp-VBmY-yZL5-o2QB-QDR9-5H3d-GF6wWo 
    ├─/dev/mapper/ubuntu--mate--vg-root ext4                 4428cf56-5be1-4a51-8918-954ab0628cf5   /
    └─/dev/mapper/ubuntu--mate--vg-swap_1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In fact, `verbose` is missing in the command, so there was no `output` explicitly but it is not really `failed`. Let us check this fact:

```
$ sudo grub-probe --target=cryptodisk_uuid -d /dev/sda
$ echo $?
0
```

So the output of `echo $?` confirms that the command was successful but no output displayed because `verbose` option is missing.

So, you must run the command with `verbose` option in order to display an output as follows:

```
$ sudo grub-probe --verbose --target=cryptodisk_uuid -d /dev/sda
(or)
$ sudo grub-probe -v --target=cryptodisk_uuid -d /dev/sda
```

That is it!

Comment: -v still does not return a UUID for /dev/sdaX, at least for my systems. See https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ykWhVsJBRv/

Comment: From the logs, you can clearly observe that **/boot/grub/device.map** is missing. The device map is not installed by default along with grub2. In order to generate a `device map`, you must run the command `sudo grub-mkdevicemap -v`. This lodges  **device.map** into the `/boot/grub` directory.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is correct.  Grub is supposed to "probe" the actual devices.  How else can grub create a device map?  Also, some grub output messages say "probing devices".

Comment: Please refer `man grub-probe` which didn't mention anything about **creating** `device map` by itself. BTW, what happened to your problem in hand, @d0006? You wanted UUID to be returned by the grub-probe command. Were you successful? Please reply. Thanks.